# Java Object array java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am having a problem where I create an array of objects but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when i try to address something to it.

this is the class with the problem.

```
public class Blocks {
public static Block[] b = new Block[8];

public Blocks() throws IOException {
    new Air  (b[0]);
    new Stone(b[1]);
    new Grass(b[2]);
    new Dirt (b[3]);
}
```

this is the class Block.

```
public class Block {
private Texture Texture = null;
private int S = World.BLOCK_SIZE;
private boolean hasTexture = true;
private String texturePath = null;

public void setTexture(String path) throws IOException {
    this.texturePath = path;
    Texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
}

public void draw(int Xa, int Ya) {

    GL11.glTranslatef(Xa, Ya, 0);
    //GL11.glRotatef(0, 0, 1, 0);
    //GL11.glRotatef(0, 1, 0, 0);

    if(hasTexture) {
    Texture.bind();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
        //GL11.glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, S);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(S, S);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(S, 0);

        GL11.glEnd();
    }
}

void hasTexture(boolean b) {
    this.hasTexture = b;
}

}
```

please let me know if i need to provide more info/code

Comment: You should provide error information (error message, line, stacktrace)

Comment: I think there is a problem with getting the texture: Texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File(path)));

Comment: texture is null and when you are trying to work with null object you get NullPointerException

Comment: Use static initializer block for static fields, or static lazy getter. And assign objects to your array properly: b[0] = new Block()

Comment: I suspect the answer will lie in the stack trace you didn't provide.

Comment: Downvoting this into oblivion isn't really helpful. Yes it could be improved, but no need to go ballistic on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it this way

```
public class Blocks {
public static Block[] b = new Block[8];

static {
   // Instantiating the objects present in the array
   for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
       b[i] = new Block();
}

public Blocks() throws IOException {
   // Now you can access them
    new Air  (b[0]);
    new Stone(b[1]);
    new Grass(b[2]);
    new Dirt (b[3]);
}
```

You forgot to instantiate the objects present in the array. So it is prompting null pointer exception

Comment: It is not a good idea to initialize static field within a constructor. Static initializer block or static (lazy) getter would be a better idea.

Comment: @skuntsel Yeah right! Otherwise whenever a new object is created the array would have set to initial value. Thanks for correcting me. I have updated my answer with it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks. this fixed it. so i have to init the obects also?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can look into this:-

```
public static Block[] b = new Block[8];

public Blocks() throws IOException {
    new Air  (b[0]);
    new Stone(b[1]);
    new Grass(b[2]);
    new Dirt (b[3]);
}
```

You've not instantiated the array elements. `b[0], b[1], etc..` are still `null` references.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you are creating an empty array named b with 8 slots (of type block), and then instantiating objects (such as `new Air  (b[0]);`) using references to the (empty) array.

If the constructor for Air can't handle a null argument that may be the source of your null pointer exception

Try putting some objects in `b` first